# Need postgis/postgres query to build array of wkt points based on nearest distance to wkts in table (not nearest neighbor - need array for all wkts!)

Tags: postgis

Lets say I have a postgres table with two columns wkt (well known text of "Point") and geom (point). For instance see this table below (example table name: wkt_geom):

| wkt | geom |
| --- | --- |
| Point(-118.7 35.29) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC085EB51B81EA54140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.39) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC052B81E85EBB14140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.49) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC01F85EB51B8BE4140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.59) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0EC51B81E85CB4140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.69) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0B81E85EB51D84140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.79) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC085EB51B81EE54140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.89) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC052B81E85EBF14140 |
| Point(-118.7 35.99) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC01F85EB51B8FE4140 |
| Point(-118.7 36.09) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0EC51B81E850B4240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.19) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0B81E85EB51184240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.29) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC085EB51B81E254240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.39) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC052B81E85EB314240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.49) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC01F85EB51B83E4240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.59) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0EC51B81E854B4240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.69) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0B81E85EB51584240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.79) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC085EB51B81E654240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.89) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC052B81E85EB714240 |
| Point(-118.7 36.99) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC01F85EB51B87E4240 |
| Point(-118.7 37.09) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0EC51B81E858B4240 |
| Point(-118.7 37.19) | 0101000020E6100000CDCCCCCCCCAC5DC0B81E85EB51984240 |

What I need is a query that for every wkt in the table, can build an array of the four nearest/distinct points from the table (including the point being compared) so that for any wkt, would have:

| wkt | array_json |
| --- | --- |
| Point(-118.7 35.29) | ["Point(-118.7 35.29)","Point(-118.7 35.39)","Point(-118.7 35.49)","Point(-118.7 35.59)"] |

Here is the query I used to build the example:

```sql
select 'Point(-118.7 35.29)' as wkt, array_to_json(array_agg(sq.wkt)) as array_json from
    (select sq.wkt from
        (select distinct sq.wkt, sq.geom
        from
            (with terr as materialized 
                (select eigen_group, geom from milkshake_territories_v1 where zone_id = 1)
            select distinct t1.wkt, st_geomfromtext(t1.wkt)::geometry(Point, 4326) as geom, terr.eigen_group as territory
            from
                (select wkt, st_geomfromtext(wkt)::geometry(Point, 4326) as geom from thi_cali_valley) t1, terr
            where st_contains(terr.geom, t1.geom)) sq
        limit 20) sq
    order by st_distancesphere(st_geomfromtext('Point(-118.7 35.29)')::geometry(Point, 4326), sq.geom) limit 4) sq
```

Seems like a chicken-egg thing and I am struggling :). Not a nearest neighbor thing either because I need an array for each wkt in the table (actual table is 10,000+ wkts) Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can do a KNN search, and once you have the 4 nearest neighbors you can aggregate them into an array. See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/finding-nearest-neighbor-for-each-point-in-the-same-table) (change the limit and make sure to have an index on the cast to geography)

Comment: @JGH - thank you for the post. Extremely helpful. Two things for anyone else: 1st use a cross join lateral (so helpful ... see my answer) and 2nd need geometry index!

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented within a Python script (using PsycoPG2):

```
drop table if exists temp_nearby_grps;
create temp table temp_nearby_grps as
    with terr as materialized 
        (select eigen_group, geom from milkshake_territories_v1 where zone_id = 1)
    select distinct t1.wkt, st_geomfromtext(t1.wkt)::geometry(Point, 4326) as geom, terr.eigen_group as territory
    from
        (select wkt, st_geomfromtext(wkt)::geometry(Point, 4326) as geom from thi_cali_valley) t1, terr
    where st_contains(terr.geom, t1.geom);
create index temp_nearby_grps_geom_idx
    on temp_nearby_grps using GIST(geom);

select t1_wkt as wkt, array_to_json(array_agg(t2_wkt)) as nearby_grps
from 
    (select distinct t1.wkt as t1_wkt, t2.wkt as t2_wkt, 
        round((st_distance(t1.geom::geography, t2.geom::geography) / 1000)::numeric,2) as km_dist
    from temp_nearby_grps as t1
    cross join lateral (
        select wkt, geom 
        from temp_nearby_grps
        order by t1.geom::geography <-> geom::geography
        limit 4
    ) as t2
    order by t1.wkt, round((st_distance(t1.geom::geography, t2.geom::geography) / 1000)::numeric,2)) sq
group by t1_wkt;
```